# R: Selecting All Neighbors of Degree "N" in a Graph

Tags: r

I am trying to learn how to extract all neighbors of "degree n" for some node in a graph.

For example suppose I have a graph that contains friendships amongst groups of people. Suppose I select "John" and want friends of degree = 2. This means that I select :

- John
- All of John's friends
- All of the friends of John's friends

I tried to do this in R using the "ego()" function:

```
#https://igraph.org/r/doc/ego.html#:~:text=ego%20calculates%20the%20neighborhoods%20of,vertex%2C%20edge%20and%20graph%20attributes. 
library(igraph)

# create a graph
g <- graph(c(1,2, 1,3, 2,4, 3,4, 4,5, 5,6, 5,7))

# get all neighbors of node 1 with degree 2
neighbors_of_1_degree_2 <- unique(c(ego(g, 1, order=1)$name, ego(g, 1, order=2)$name)[-1])
print(neighbors_of_1_degree_2)
```

But this is giving me a NULL output.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work?

```
induced.subgraph(g, unlist(ego(g, order=2, nodes="1")))

IGRAPH 3d02cf8 D--- 4 4 -- 
+ edges from 3d02cf8:
[1] 1->2 1->3 2->4 3->4
```

Is this correct?